# Javascript/JQuery same drop down menu for all list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

Okay I am trying to simply create a dynamic list that generates the same drop down menu using JQuery or Javascript.

```
<ul id="main-list">
    <li value="a" class="dd-list-item"> A </li>
    <li value="b" class="dd-list-item"> B </li>
    <li value="c" class="dd-list-item"> C </li>
</ul>

<ul class="list-menu">
    <li>Rename </li>
    <li>Delete</li>
</ul>

<form>
      <input type="text" id="text-input" placeholder="New item"/>
      <input type="button" id="btn" value="Add New"/>
</form>
```

Above is a chunk of the HTML code. Now below is the JQuery code to implement adding the new item to the list.

```
$(function(){
let list= $('#main-list');    
let button = $('#btn');

button.on('click', function(){
     let value = $('#text-input').val();
     list.append("<li  class='dd-list-item'>" + value + "</li>");
});

$('.list-menu').clone().appendTo('.dd-list-item');

});
```

This is the closest I have gotten thus far to dynamically add new list item, but I haven't been successful with creating a drop down with the same options for the listed items. Any ideas how to effectively go about it?

[image: Expected Outcome]

Comment: if you add value what will be your expected output ? can u show us your expected output ?

Comment: I made this picture on paint to illustrate what I am trying to do. @MinarMnr

Answer (score 1):

You have an issue with your quotes. The quotes in the HTML snippet are not being replaced.

Instead of

```
list.append("<li  class="dd-list-item">" + value + "</li>");
```

Use

```
list.append('<li  class="dd-list-item">' + value + "</li>");
```

(With fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/9401/)

Comment: I typed in the code in the text area, I didn't copy and paste it. Beside the HTML issue, I am trying to figure out how to get the dynamic drop down for each listed item, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

like this :
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FH6GZAFJOEHS

Script :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

let list= $('#main-list');    
let button = $('#btn');

button.on('click', function(){
     let value = $('#text-input').val();
     list.append("<li  class='dd-list-item'>" + value + "</li>");
});

button.on('click', function(){
     let value = $('#text-input').val();
     $(".list-menu").append("<li>" + value + "</li>");
});
});
```

Comment: This is incorrect from what I am trying to achieve. If you look at the picture, when you enter anything in the text area and click add, it adds it to the list. But what I want to achieve is that each listed item have a drop down menu, that displays  "Rename" and "Delete". @MinarMhr

Comment: Alternatively, when ever I click on a list, the same menu options pop up.